# A word for someone who never had a mate because he/she has a high standard

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any better word than *picky*?

Comment: Could be *lonely*?

Comment: **Virgin** (somewhat tongue-in-cheek).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about *romantic (or relational) perfectionist*?

> They developed the Multidimensional Romantic Perfectionism Questionnaire (MRPQ), to assess seven aspects of romantic perfectionism [...] (7) prescribed romantic perfectionism for one's partner (i. e., the tendency to have rigid, inflexible standards for one's own romantic partner).

<sup>"[The Effects of Romantic Perfectionism on Disclosure in Romantic Relationships](http://www.kon.org/urc/v4/bailey.html)," Dustin P. Bailey
William E. Snell, Jr.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

`fastidious` might fit in that description

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fastidious

Answer (score 4):

You might consider "particular" as in "She's very particular about prospective mates."

From [The Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/particular):

> **particular** [pəˈtɪkjʊlə]
>   *adj*
>   ... 4. exacting or difficult to please, esp in details; fussy

If that's not strong enough, you could use *over-particular*.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I could find is [non-random mating](http://anthro.palomar.edu/synthetic/synth_8.htm) without resorting to words like "discriminating", "selective":

> Even without the intervention of
>   farmers, most animals select mates
>   carefully--they do not mate randomly. 
>   Charles Darwin noted this fact in his
>   1871 book Descent of Man and Selection
>   in Relation to Sex.  He suggested that
>   mate selection is a powerful force of
>   evolution similar in its effect to
>   natural selection.  This idea was
>   widely rejected in Darwin's time, but
>   later research showed that he was
>   correct.

see also [assortative mating or assortative pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortative_mating)

> Assortative mating (also called
>   assortative pairing) is the phenomenon
>   where a sexually reproducing organism
>   chooses to mate with individuals that
>   are similar (positive
>   assortative mating) or dissimilar
>   (negative assortative mating) to
>   itself in some specific manner. In
>   evolution, these two types of
>   assortative mating have the effect,
>   respectively, of increasing or
>   reducing the range of variation (trait
>   variance), when the assorting is cued
>   on heritable traits. Positive
>   assortative mating, therefore, results
>   in disruptive natural selection, and
>   negative assortative mating results in
>   stabilized natural selection.

using those terms you could probably use something like "assortative selection" or "positive assortative selection". If someone was picky in the opposite sense (i.e. going for more diversity) then it would be [disassortive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassortative_mating) mating (or arguably, "pairing"):

> Disassortative sexual selection is a
>   form of sexual selection in which one
>   sex chooses the other, in such a way
>   that the offspring benefits from the
>   diversity of the parental genotypes

You can also try [homogamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogamy) (or "homogamous")

> Homogamy is marriage between
>   individuals who are, in some
>   culturally important way, similar to
>   each other. Homogamy may be based on
>   socio-economic status, class, gender,
>   ethnicity, or religion. It is a
>   form of assortative mating.It can also
>   refer to the socialization customs of
>   a particular group; such that people
>   who are similar in religion, class,
>   gender, or culture tend to socialize
>   with one another.

or even [heterogamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogamy) or "heterogamous":

> In a sociology, heterogamy refers to a
>   marriage between two individuals that
>   differ in a certain criterion, and is
>   contrasted with homogamy for marriage
>   or union between partners that match
>   according to that criterion. For
>   example, ethnic heterogamy refers to
>   marriages involving individuals of
>   different ethnic groups. Age
>   heterogamy refers to marriages
>   involving partners of significantly
>   different ages. Heterogamy and
>   homogamy are also used to describe
>   marriage or union between people of
>   unlike and like sex (or gender)
>   respectively.

so to answer you question - that person might probably a non-random mate selector/an assortative selector/a disassortative selector/a homogamist/a heterogamist

Comment: +1 for homogamy and (if I could) another for heterogamy.  I'm using these the next time anyone allows me near a discussion of same-sex marriage.

Answer (score 2):

> She's too choosy about mates.

Answer (score 2):

**Too Picky / Too Selective**

For example,

> She's too [selective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selective) when it comes to romantic partners. That's why she's never found one.

or

> She's too [picky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/picky) when it comes to romantic partners. That's why she's never found one.

Answer (score 0):

uncompromising can fit sometimes

> showing an unwillingness to make concessions to others, especially by changing one's ways or opinions

ODE