# Is there any proper word for a person who is very hard to please?

Tags: single-word-requests

I searched on Google - but mainly find "difficult" / "demanding". I am just wondering if there is any more appropriate word?

Comment: http://thesaurus.com is a great place to get lists of words.

Comment: How about a person that "has high standards?"

Comment: Also see [A word for someone who never had a mate because he/she has a high standard](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28779/a-word-for-someone-who-never-had-a-mate-because-he-she-has-a-high-standard),

Comment: I'd've said *yours truly*, but that's two words. :)

Comment: @tchrist lol :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/hard-to-please) here is the list of words:

> **Main Entry:   hard-to-please**
>   **Part of Speech:** adjective
>   
> **Definition:**    extremely particular
>   
> **Synonyms:**  choosy, critical, demanding, detailed, finicky, fussy, meticulous, nit-picking, particular, picky, scrutinizing
>   Antonyms:   undemanding

Answer (score 2):

*[Persnickety](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persnickety)*, “Fastidious or fussy”; “Obsessive about mundane details, demanding for precision” is good in this context, and also *[fastidious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fastidious)*, “Excessively particular, demanding, or fussy about details”;
“Difficult to please; quick to find fault”.

Answer (score 2):

The term *scrupulous* is often used to indicate a demanding nature, often with regard to ones own behaviour. [Webster's Collegiate](http://www.yourdictionary.com/scrupulous) defines it as

> extremely careful to do the precisely right, proper, or correct thing in every last detail

Another option is *punctilious*, also often used to describe the conduct of the decribed person.  [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/punctilious)  defines it as

> 1.paying scrupulous attention to correctness in etiquette
>
> 2.attentive to detail

Answer (score 1):

[The thesaurus yields a few alternatives](http://thesaurus.com/browse/demanding), but I think the most suitable would is:

> [**querulous**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/querulous)
>
> Definition: Grouchy, hard to please

Comment: It just feels like its a bit negative like quarrelsome ( `complaining`)

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: mmm - just something neutral

Answer (score 0):

For a neutral option, you could use "selective", or "discriminating", so long as your context makes it clear that the discrimination exercised is not racist, sexist, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I often hear *[high-maintenance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high-maintenance)* bandied about for this sort of person:

> (figuratively, pejorative, of a person) requiring a lot of attention
>   or reassurance; emotionally needy

It suggests someone who requires a lot of work i.e. is difficult to please.